# Data Type of field from sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Is it possible to get the datatype of a given field from a sequelize model. Assume we have a module defined like so

```
User = sequelize.define 'User',
{
 id:
   type: DataTypes.UUID
   primaryKey: true
   defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
 firstName:
   type: DataTypes.STRING
   allowNull: false
 middleName:
   type: DataTypes.STRING
   allowNull: true
   defaultValue: null
 lastName:
   type: DataTypes.STRING
   allowNull: true
   defaultValue: null
}
```

I need to say figure out the data type for firstName. Is there any method within model which can achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access it this way:

```
User.tableAttributes.firstName.type.constructor.key
```